Compile gem5 ends with no binary file but no error
there! I am compiling gem5 according to the very simple tutorial on their webpage. However, I fail to finish this. It shows that I cannot link an .opt file at the end. I will list the env I used and some vital outputs below. Thanks a lot if anyone could help with this!
Gem5 - 24.0.0.1
Ubuntu - 20.04
Scons - 4.7.0
Python - 3.12.2
Exception ignored in tp_clear of: <class 'multidict'>
TypeError: Missed attribute 'n_fields' of type time.struct_time

 [     CXX] X86/python/m5/info.py.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] src/base/date.cc -> X86/base/date.o
scons: done building targets.
*** Summary of Warnings ***
Warning: Header file <capstone/capstone.h> not found.
         This host has no capstone library installed.
Warning: Couldn't find HDF5 C++ libraries. Disabling HDF5 support.

Every step is completely the same with the tutorial.

install them first.
sudo apt install libhdf5-dev libcapstone-dev

then delete build dir.
rm -rf build

finally, rebuild it.
